# Android: How do I save an ImageView to SharedPreferences for save and retrieve?

Tags: java, android, imageview, sharedpreferences, onactivityresult

I am creating an application and am currently wondering how do I save an image to SharedPreferences, and then retrieve that same image, please see below the code I have regarding the Images. What do I need to add to this?

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Checks if the intent was able to pick the image and if it was successful
    if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        // Get selected image uri from phone gallery
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        // Display selected photo in image view
        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
    }

    // Handle Camera Request
    else if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        // Bitmap variable to store data
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

        // Display taken picture in image view
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }


    else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_AFTER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Uri selectedImageAfter = data.getData();

        imageView2.setImageURI(selectedImageAfter);
    }

    else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_AFTER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Bitmap bitmapAfter = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

        imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmapAfter);
    }
}
```

Comment: which one selectedImage, or selectedImageAfter bitmapAfter ?

Comment: I would like to store the bitmap to SharedPreferences

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that, but you can save the bitmap as a file into your device storage and store the path of this file using SharedPreferences

Comment: Yes that would work also, how can I do this?

Comment: To make things more simple, could you please explain to me how your app works, I see that you get an image or capture it from the camera right

Comment: Yes when selecting the upload button the user has 2 options; to select an item in their gallery or to upload their own image. Either way I would like both of these options to be saved and be able to be retrieved upon launching the application.

Comment: I've provided an answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save and restore the `Bitmap` associated to the `ImageView`, you can save a Base64 encoding of this Bitmap in the `SharedPreferences`.

Here is an example,

```
//get SharedPreferences
private static final String PREF_BITMAP_KEY = "PREF_BITMAP_KEY";
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//get Bitmap and Base64 encoding
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
String b64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

//save in SharedPreference
prefs.edit().putString(PREF_BITMAP_KEY, b64);
prefs.edit().commit();
```

To restore the Bitmap:

```
String b64 = prefs.getString(PREF_BITMAP_KEY, null); 
if (!TextUtils.isNullOrEmpty(b64)) {
  byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(b64, Base64.DEFAULT);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always use this library it's make things easier : `implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.30.0'`

The two methods below allows you to save as well as store the saved image path using `SharedPreferences`

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Checks if the intent was able to pick the image and if it was successful
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            // Get selected image uri from phone gallery
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            // Display selected photo in image view
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);

            //Store image path
            String imagePath = UriUtils.uri2File(selectedImage).getAbsolutePath();
            storeImage(imagePath);
        }

        // Handle Camera Request
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            // Bitmap variable to store data
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // Display taken picture in image view
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            //Save and store image path
            saveImage(bitmap);

        } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_AFTER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Uri selectedImageAfter = data.getData();

            imageView2.setImageURI(selectedImageAfter);
            
            
            //Store image path
            String imagePath = UriUtils.uri2File(selectedImageAfter).getAbsolutePath();
            storeImage(imagePath);
            
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_AFTER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Bitmap bitmapAfter = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmapAfter);


            //Save and store image path
            saveImage(bitmapAfter);
            
        }
    }


    public void storeImage(String imagePath) {
        SPUtils.getInstance().put("savedImage", imagePath);
    }

    public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        //Save image to device storage
        File imageFile = new File(PathUtils.getExternalPicturesPath(), "cachedImage.jpg");
        boolean isSaved = ImageUtils.save(bitmap, imageFile, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG);
        if (isSaved) storeImage(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

To get the stored image, use the following :

```
public void loadImage() {
        //Load the saved Image
        String imagePath = SPUtils.getInstance().getString("savedImage");
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imagePath)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I have implemented the : implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.30.0' and the .getExternalPicturesPath doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Kevin make sure to import the PathUtils  `import com.blankj.utilcode.util.PathUtils;`

Comment: What do you mean by this? The .getExternalPicturesPath is in red and is not recognised

Comment: Yes this is added, unfortunately still not working

Comment: Ummm, weird, it should work, change it to `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

Comment: My mistake; I had it in as androidx.core.graphics as I copy and pasted over. I changed it to com.blankj.utilcode.util.PathUtils and it is working now. As for the loadImage() method, where do I place this?

Comment: When you want to load the stored image call it, for example in another activity or somewhere else

Comment: Unfortunately the Glide and CustomTarget is shown in red so the method doesn't work

Comment: You need to add   `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'` as well

Comment: Perfect got it implemented now. Where do I add the loadImage() I have tried running the application and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: This is based on you, you who decide where you want to load the stored image, e.g. in another activities

Comment: I have added the above methods into a Fragment, and would like to save and load these 2 images both within the same fragment, I have tried adding the loadImage() below the saveImage() in the onActivityResult() and doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have added the above methods into a Fragment, and would like to save and load these 2 images both within the same fragment, I have tried adding the loadImage() below the saveImage() in the onActivityResult() and doesn't seem to work